# No component factory found for Component for angular2-modal

Tags: angular

I am trying to Implement Angular2-modal with angular version 2.0.1 version. The moment I change the angular version to latest which is 2.0.1 i getting below error:

[image]

Below is the plunker:

```
"https://plnkr.co/edit/ZeRajGkGwyvKRIZkG4XQ?p=preview"
```

Seems like its an issue with angular2-modal, can anyone fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

add this to your app module

`entryComponents: [ AdditionCalculateWindow ]`

Comment: Thank you, I thought entryComponents got deprecated in angular 2.0.0 versions, and I moved AdditionCalculateWindow into declarations section. we should be adding in both declaration and entryComponents ?

Comment: I thought they did as well, I suppose not though. I only knew to do that because I took a look at the plunkr example on the angular2-modal repo http://embed.plnkr.co/mbPzd8/

Comment: custom popup is occupying entire width of the page, its not aligned and not centered. how can we set proper width to the custom pop, I updated the plunker when u open it in browser full window it is occupying full space width which is kind of ugly. Do you know how to set width for the custom popup ?